# How to update radio group status in a metabox?

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, radio-group, meta-boxes

I have implemented radio-group option in WordPress metabox. I got the desire radio group in meta box with respective label, but I failed to update my checked status on selecting radio or saving the post where I am using it. I think there is something I need to put.

```
<div class="my radio group">
<h2>my radio group </h2>

 <?php

  $cars = array('BMW', 'FERRARI', 'PORSCHE', 'BENTALI', 'MRX', 'CHEVROLET');


 foreach ($cars as $car) {
    echo  '<input name="my-best-car" type="radio"  onchange="javascript:document.post.submit()"';
    $option = 'id=" ' .$car . '"';
    $option = '<value="' . $car . '"';

    if ($car == $my_favorite_car) $option .= "checked";
    $option .= '>';
    $option .= '<label for=" '.$car .' ">' . $car .'  ';

    $option .=  '</label>';
    echo $option;
  }
 ?>
</div>
```

WordPress meta box save function is also added. My other option type like text, select & checkbox updating properly.
While I trying to update my RADIO-GROUP meta values using:

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'my-best-car', $_POST['my-best-car'], true);
```

Comment: if ($car == $my_favorite_car) $option .= "checked='checked'"; maybe like this?

Comment: Thanks friend! I am just checking your suggestion.

Comment: Assuming your $_POST sends correct values and only problem would be to set checked radio I believe this would solve it

Comment: Tried it but not working, I want to update radio selection as well as want to grab the checked key value. Thats way if BMW is selected ,I want to save selection in variable $my-best-car for further process.

Comment: Where does your form post request after submit? on same page I assume ? And where do you set $my_favorite_car var? And whats in update_post_meta function?

Comment: Actually same thing is done by using select type which is working properly. And $my-best-car is used on same page where metabox is updated. This way on selection of particular car name  displays my another div box for information related to that car. $my-best-car is used for toggling my hidden divs.

Comment: well do the var_dump($_POST) and see if the values you are looking for are there and also you vars $car and $my_favorite_car

Comment: I tried it, getting only array(0) { }

Comment: Ok can you put all you code somewhere so I can see it, unfortunately you don't have enough reputation to chat

Comment: You should post your full code. It is not possible to diagnose only with this fragment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found your mistake in foreach loop you have one < extra before the value so the line would look like this:

```
$option = 'value="' . $car . '"';
```

Also your js is not submitting the form so just add js function in head like this for example:

```
<script>
   function submitOnClick(formName){
       document.forms[formName].submit();
   }
</script>
```

And in the form instead of:

```
onchange="javascript:document.post.submit()"
```

put

```
onclick="submitOnClick(\'myForm\')"
```

I tried it and it works you just need to rename your form name accordingly

Comment: Hey Friend thanks a lot for your valuable comment.But its not working for me as I did it same thing for this using select box. I pasted my metabox code here http://pastebin.com/0twzLA0u

Comment: Did you try to change onclick="submitOnClick(\'myForm\')" ?

Comment: Thanks Vodich! I did it just by removing an extra < 
from this line  $option = '<value="' . $car . '"';
Now my radio status is updating without help of javascript and form method. I will take yours method in account too to check better usability.